# Dialog of intellij not show the result

Tags: java, swing, awt

[enter image description here][1] I wrote a program in intellij aide but result does not show in the intellij dialog.
The program is to draw a line in java but i don't know why it does not show
      import java.awt.*;
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

```
public void painCompenent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

    int n=6;
    int w=getWidth();
    int h=getHeight();

    int i,j;
    for (i = 0;i <= n; i++) {
        j=n-1;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(i*w/n,0,0,j*h/n);

    }


}
```

}

```
  `



import javax.swing.*;
```

import java.awt.*;

public class Faradarss {

public static void main(String args[]){

```
   MyPanel panel=new MyPanel();
   JFrame app = new JFrame();
   app.add(panel);
   app.setSize(300,300);
   app.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   app.setVisible(true);
```

}

}

Comment: Because you did not override the method. Fix the typo (or even better, let IntelliJ override the method for you) and try again. For next time, please post the code instead of images of the code

Answer (score -1):

Update your painCompenent method in MyPanel class as below:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
       ....
}
```

Thanks.